# What to do next since im unable to set sdk location and nothing is showing in the box?

Tags: android-studio

As you can see ther's nothing in box and hence not clickable

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DGTk.jpg)

Comment: You can click on the Edit button and specify the directory where you want the SDK to be installed.

Comment: It'd be more helpful for future question-askers who may run into the same issue if you actually copied and pasted the error message itself into your question rather than linking to an external image.